# Front Controller + MVC, public files issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2

i'm trying to implement a self made MVC + front controller project, after 2 days of hard work, all seems to be ok. But today i discover an curious bug on my app.

When i request an url with 2 (or more) slashes (for example www.site.com/home/show) my css, js files wont work.

I'm not an apache expert then i think i fail something there...

my virtualhost file (O.S. Ubuntu):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin baro.luc@gmail.com
ServerName servername

DocumentRoot /path_to_project/project_folder
<Directory /path_to_project/project_folder>
    Options FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

I followed that example for my project: https://github.com/Jontyy/PHP-Basic-MVC-Framework

Comment: And if you look at the HTML rendered, how different from the url working is the `<header>` of the one not working?

Comment: all the "www.site.com/something" URLs work nicely, but when i type something like "www.site.com/controllername/methodname/etc/etc" my css request become "controllername/public/stylesheets/style.css", instead of simply "public/stylesheets/style.css"

Comment: Open firebug/developer tools, go to "Network" tab, refresh your page (with 2 slashes you mentioned), then check if CSS and JS files returned 404 not found or not. If so, try adjusting their paths so they can be found during page load.

Comment: try adding / for the path, so it will be <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/stylesheets/style.css" />

Comment: How is setup the link to your css/js in your view?

Comment: like <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/stylesheets/style.css" /> but i think i resolve that by passing an absolute path to stlye.css!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by passing an absolute path to my css/js files like that:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.site.com/public/stylesheets/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.site.com/public/javascripts/script.js" ></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this lines in your virtual host configuration:

```
<Directory /path_to_project/project_folder>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```